# Fatal error: Call to undefined function: imagecreate()

Tags: php, graphics

I'm trying to put some graphics on a web page and at my prototype at the computer it's all working fine at the localhost. But now I uploaded the files to a server and I'm having a problem to plot some graphics. In my computer they are plotted, but on the server they are not.

I'm getting this error
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function ImageCreate() in /home/t1g01/phplot.php  on line 248`

Line 248

`$this->img = ImageCreate($this->image_width, $this->image_height);`

I'm using phplot, and I uploaded the files form phplot too. Can anyone help me ?

Sorry for any mistake in English and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This means your installation of php doesn't have the gd library installed/enabled.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Answer (score 44):

If you are using a Linux machine then execute this command from console:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

to install the php_gd2.dll extension. It will then work after an Apache restart.

PS: should first check your current php version

```
php -v
```

In My Case:

> PHP 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 3 2019
>   10:00:24) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.3.5, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache
>   v7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by
>   Zend Technologies

So, my PHP version is 7.3, so, the command for my version is :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd
```

Comment: Simplest solution for any linux system. This also works for nginx.

Comment: Ubuntu 16: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd`

Comment: if using PHP 7.2 `sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd`

Comment: Don't forget `service apache2 restart` !

Answer (score 9):

Your server most like does not have GD (the built in PHP image processing library) enabled. You can check this by looking for "GD" in the output of :

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

If not, check the PHP docs on how to enable it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 8):

**For Fedora, CentOS**

```
dnf install php-gd
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

**On Ubuntu**

```
apt-cache search php*-gd
apt-get install php<version>-gd
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

**Windows** users see: http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Answer (score 4):

for any php version the command for ubuntu installation is

```
apt-get install php-gd
```

it will install the version that matches your php version, and it will be later updated when you will upgrade php version.

Answer (score 3):

1. Copy the file php_gd2.dll from your PHP's ext/ directory to where
   you have your php extensions. (No need to copy if php_gd2.dll is in the extension
   dir already. Look in php.ini for 'extension_dir' directive to
   find what is your current extension directory)
2. Modify your php.ini and change the following line:

`;extension=php_gd2.dll`

to:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your GD library is not being used. Double check your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I've just recently came across this same Fatal error: Call to undefined function: imagecreate() issue while doing some QR coding using a fresh Xampp install on Windows.

I resolved the issue by first looking in the php.ini file for the GD extension and fixed the issue by uncommenting
;extension=gd

Afterwards QR code was generated to the browser as expected.

NOTE: Don't forget to restart Apache to make the change stick.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

Stop and then restart Apache Server.

PS: should first check your current php version

```
php -v
```

In My Case:

> PHP 7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  3 2019
>   10:00:24) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.3.5, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.3.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

So, my PHP version is 7.3, so, the command for my version is :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Update for PHP 7.4.0 >**

You **should not** install any external libraries !

As stated in [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php):

> As of PHP 7.4.0, --with-png-dir and --with-zlib-dir have been removed. libpng and zlib are required.

PHP 7.4.0 and newer versions comes bundled with libpng and zlib **by default**.

So all you merely need to do is to uncomment **gd** extension in `php.ini` file:

`;extension=gd` -> `extension=gd`

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Following [Gayan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37887605/11029035), for centOS, this worked for me:

```
yum install php-gd
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont forget restart apache or php-fpm if not running after installation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31110422)

Answer (score -2):

Does not accept every image extension(path)
ex. image.webp -> not upload
If you installed it somehow, you need to delete it from the files
XMAPP/xmappfiles/htdocs/opencart(opsional)/image
If you delete the file with a different extension from the given directory, the problem will be solved.

Comment: This answer does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require any clarification from the asker