# Laravel return view not working

Tags: php, apache, laravel, centos7

My Laravel server Ip is 192.168.1.250. It is running Centos7, apache web server and php 7. I also added `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vls/public` to httpd.conf to redirect requests to Laravel public folder.

Accessing this ip from browser when I have the following code in routs/web.php return error.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

returns:

> This page isn’t working
>       192.168.1.250 is currently unable to handle this request.
>       HTTP ERROR 500

But this route returns 'Hello':

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello';
});
```

I tried chmod 777 on app directory, resources directory, views directory and even welcome.blade.php file. Still not working. By the way everything works fine when using php artisan server command. I'm a bit confused what is going on. Any help is appreciated in advance.

.htaccess file content inside public directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have your .htaccess well defined?

Comment: You mean the .htaccess inside public folder?

Comment: Are you sure the apache configuration is ok? It seems to be a more general issue than laravel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187647/apache-localhost-is-currently-unable-to-handle-this-request-php-request

Comment: That is a very generic server error message. Anything could be failing. You really must take a look to your logs to see what's the specific error. If not, is like coding blindfold.

Comment: copy the htaccess to the root directory of your project and change the name of server.php to index.php and check

Comment: Take a look at `storage/logs/laravel.log` and post the latest error here.

Comment: Are you sure you have `welcome.blade.php`?

Comment: Also post related apache logs... var/httpd/logs/error***.log

Comment: no blade to render in ur case! Missing view

Comment: Thanks @georgeos. After checking apache log file I found that I should disable seLinux. I used this command `echo 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce`

Comment: Check that you have /resources/views/welcome.blade.php and also check the permissions (755) on your /storage/app/framework/cache and /storage/app/framework/views.

Comment: Excellent! @Beginner