# How can I fix 'Call to undefined function ImageCreate()' error when creating a QR code in PHP?

Tags: php

I am Trying to create Qr-code Of my data but it is giving an Fatal error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ImageCreate()
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\voting\phpqrcode\qrimage.php:74 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\voting\phpqrcode\qrimage.php(32): QRimage::image(Array, 3, 4) 
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\voting\phpqrcode\qrencode.php(494): QRimage::png(Array, false, 3, 4, false) 
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\voting\phpqrcode\qrencode.php(286): QRencode->encodePNG('helo', false, false) 
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\voting\qrcode.php(11): QRcode::png('helo') 
> #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\voting\phpqrcode\qrimage.php on line 74

To generate Qr code of my data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Call to undefined function: imagecreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106991/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imagecreate). Did it occur to you to just google the error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Copying the complete error message into your question is good, we often see only a very short summary. The actual PHP code in which the error occurs would be a nice addition.