# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ImageCreate()

Tags: php, gd, gd2

I am getting following error while generating qrcode in php.

Error:

> `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ImageCreate()`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ImageCreate() in E:\files\includes\phpqrcode\qrimage.php:74 
Stack trace:
#0 E:\files\includes\phpqrcode\qrimage.php(32): QRimage::image(Array, 5, 4)
#1 E:\files\includes\phpqrcode\qrencode.php(494): QRimage::png(Array, false, 5, 4, false)
#2 E:\files\includes\phpqrcode\qrencode.php(286): QRencode-&gt;encodePNG('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...', false, false)
#3 E:\files\generate_qr.php(12): QRcode::png('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...', false, 0, 5, 4, false)
#4 {main}
    thrown in E:\files\includes\phpqrcode\qrimage.php on line 74
```

.

.

.

I have enebled gd extension by following this question:
[Fatal error: Call to undefined function: imagecreate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106991/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imagecreate)

Following is my php.ini:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

But still getting error.

I tried changing php version, tried different php files but still getting error.

I tried running the application as administrator also.

I am using `Windows 11`.

I tried following code to check if gd extension is enebled.

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded('gd')) {
    echo "GD library is enabled.";
} else {
    echo "GD library is not enabled.";
}
?>
```

It returns: `GD library is not enabled.`.

Why is gd extension is not being enebled?

.
.
In `phpinfo();` it shows this:

> GD imaging:   Rasmus Lerdorf, Stig Bakken, Jim Winstead, Jouni Ahto,
> Ilia Alshanetsky, Pierre-Alain Joye, Marcus Boerger

Comment: Make sure you edited the _correct_ `php.ini`. If you're unsure which one is actually used, call `phpinfo()` and find out.

Comment: Also, you did restart the webserver after making changes, yes?

Comment: The file name should be `php_gd.dll` since PHP 8.

Comment: @CBroe I double checked everything. I have updated the question for `phpinfo();` response.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Also, if the gd extension is not enabled, it's obvious that the code won't work

Answer (score 0):

In the `phpinfo` output, you are looking at the CREDITS and not at the section that actually reports the extensions that are active.

These are the Credits
[image]

And this is the section you would see if the GD extension was active

[image]

I would guess that you have more than one `php.ini` file and the one you are checking/editing to activate the GD extension is not the one your system is actually using.

Look at the TOP SECTION of the `phpinfo` output, it will tell you which file is being read as `PHP.INI`

[image]